# Trying to get monkeyrunner to include an external .py file

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to get monkeyrunner to accept an external .py file. The .py file just has some functions in it, nothing fancy.

mainscript.py:

```
import unittest

import logging
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\path\to\helperscripts\")
from monkeyHelper import monkeyHelper


#log to STDERR
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class TestDepthOneFunctions(unittest.TestCase):  

def setUp(self):
    mh = monkeyHelper()
    self.device = mh.setupDevice()
    #monkeyHelper.setupDevice()


def test_myMusic(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.device,3)

def tearDown(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

monkeyHelper.py:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
import logging
import sys


class monkeyHelper(object):

    def __init__(self):
        return

    def setupDevice(self):
        return 3
```

I've tried just running 
    #>monkeyrunner.bat mainscript.py 
and it doesn't work.  I've seen the full command line that monkeyrunner.bat puts out - is there any way to add C:\path\to\helperScripts to that command line?  This is what monkeyrunner.bat spits out:

```
C:\Windows\system32\java.exe -Xmx512m -Djava.ext.dirs=lib\;lib\x86_64 -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir=..\framework -jar lib\monkeyrunner.jar mainscript.py
```

the error i'm getting is:

```
import monkeyHelper
ImportError: No module named monkeyHelper
```

I've been banging my head against this all day - any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't randomly put \ in a string, try:

```
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\helperscripts")
```

The `r` means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

Also make sure helperMonkey.py is in that path,

Comment: *FACEPALM*   Yup, that fixed it.

Comment: If that is what fixed it, you should accept eladc's answer as the correct answer (:

Answer (score 0):

If you use monkeyrunner
you can add a folder 'lib' under

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib'
```

then put your py files under

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\lib
```

if your file is called myPyFile.py

just

```
from myPyFile import *
```

update:
careful that if you going to update Android SDK tool, back up your file first, last time I update, my file in lib were deleted.